# How to disable resize for specific column in angular ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

Here is my column def

```
$scope.gridOpts = {
enableColumnResizing: true,
columnDefs : [
   {displayName:"Name",field:"name",width:'20%'},
   {displayName:"Gender",field:"gender",width:'*'},
   {displayName:"Company",field:"company",width:'60%'}
  ],
data: [
  { "name": "Ethel Price", "gender": "female", "company": "Enersol" },
  { "name": "Claudine Neal", "gender": "female", "company": "Sealoud" },
  { "name": "Beryl Rice", "gender": "female", "company": "Velity" },
  { "name": "Wilder Gonzales", "gender": "male", "company": "Geekko" }
]};
```

I would like to disable resizing on the last column (company), the current solution works okay but starts truncating and adding ellipsis when the window is reduced to a certain point.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the last column resizing set last column property `enableColumnResizing` to `false`.

```
columnDefs : [
       {displayName:"Name",field:"name",width:'20%'},
       {displayName:"Gender",field:"gender",width:'*'},       {displayName:"Company",field:"company",width:'60%',enableColumnResizing:false}
      ]
```

Adding ellipsis while resizing is expected behaviour.

If you want to control that behavior you have to set the `minWidth` property to the column definition.